# How to install opencv 2.4 and opencv 3 in same machine

Tags: python, opencv

I am working in opencv 2.4 and python 2.7.But now i got project from github which is imlemented in opencv 3.Is it possible to test that same code in my machine.

Comment: You might want to have a look at virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the package is named the same, you should probably use a second python installation to be able to test both.

You can then switch between those versions depending on the openCV version you'd like to have.

Besides of that, you can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to setup two environments for the different versions.

Comment: Thanks.I installed new python and opencv3.Copied opencv3's cv2.pyd to new python.Then i changed pycharm interpreter.It worked fine.